# How do i insert a var into sql statement on flutter sqflite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

How do i insert a var into sql statement on flutter sqflite? $Constants.dbColName doesnt work

```
  Future<int> save(Item item) async {
    final db = await database;

    return db.delete(
      Constants.dbTableName, 
      where: '$Constants.dbColName = ?',
      whereArgs: [item.name],  
    );
  }
```

Comment: add class Constants here

Comment: you probably want: `${Constants.dbColName}`?

Comment: yes you are right thanks!

Answer (score 2):

posting @pskink s comment as an answer for future reference.

---

Use parenthesis to wrap the variable.

```
${Constants.dbColName}
```